# How to let ack support more filetypes?

Tags: ack

in ack's [home page](http://betterthangrep.com/), there lists a lot of file type, but without aspx, is it possible to let ack support it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

On window,add .ackrc file under C:\Documents and Settings\yourname,with content

```
--type-set=aspx=.aspx
```

you can set a type to multi file extension,seperate by ","

```
--type-set=aspx=.aspx,.ascx
```

Note

`ack` syntax and behaviour has changed significantly with version 2. The equivalent of the above in version 2 would be:

```
--type-set=aspx:ext:aspx,ascx
```

Where the syntax is `--type-set TYPE:FILTER:FILTERARGS` and `FILTER` can be any of `ext, is, match, firstlinematch`. You should definitely read the [man page](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/) for detailed explanation.

see

- [The .ackrc file](https://metacpan.org/pod/ack#Use-the-.ackrc-file)
- [Defining your own types](https://metacpan.org/pod/ack#Defining-your-own-types)
- [ack version 2 man page](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/)

Comment: +1 The `man` page says "If you want to define a **new** type, or completely redefine an existing type, then use **`--type-set`**."

Comment: for ubuntu place .ackrc under /home/<username>/

Answer (score 12):

```
--type-add TYPE=.EXTENSION[,.EXT2[,...]]
                    Files with the given EXTENSION(s) are recognized as
                    being of (the existing) type TYPE
```

from http://betterthangrep.com/

You can add this to .ackrc in your homedirectory.

Comment: The better way to do this is with --type-set.

Comment: Yes, this answer is much better. The other one causes all your other files to no longer be found. If you're going to put this in the .ackrc file, you also need an = sign instead of space after --type-add.