# Add filetype containing dot (.blade.php) to ackrc

Tags: ack

I know how to add a new filetype to ack. This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870611/how-to-let-ack-support-more-filetypes)

For example, I added `handlebars`:

```
--type-set=hbs=.hbs
```

However, I am unable to add a filetype containg a dot, such as for `blade`

```
--type-set=blade=.blade.php
```

If I search `ack div --blade` then I get no results

Comment: Are you using ack 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I'm using version 2.12, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use ack 2.x's --type-set regex matching.

```
--type-set='blade:match:.blade.php$'
```

Look at the ack manual (`ack --man`) under "Defining your own types" for details.

Take a look at `ack --dump` to see other examples of matching.

Comment: Thanks Andy! However, I had to remove the single quotes to get it to work. `--type-set=blade:match:.blade.php$`

Comment: I had the quotes in the for if that was on the shell command line.  I guess the $ isn't going to expand to anything, but there it is anyway.